# Properties.Settings.Default fails on Release Mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, configuration

In debug mode I have been using:

```
ConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.SomeConnectionString
```

to retrieve my connection string.  However, this same code does not give me the connection string when running in release mode.

Note: SomeConnectionString is a connection string in a local Settings.settings file.

How can I use the same code above regardless of debug/release mode?

Thanks!

Comment: tried rebuilding the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a Properties file to store the connection string, you should store the connection string in app.config if you can't get access to the connection string in the web.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
     <connectionStrings>
        <add name="SomeConnectionString" 
        connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Database;
        Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=SSPI;"                       
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      <connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

Use the settings designer to set a setting of type Connection String, which will be placed in the app.config file for your csproj. Make sure you specify the scope (Application or User) appropriately.